# Optional does not throw exception when the return value is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, response, option-type

I am learning Spring Boot, I am trying to throw an exception when the service does not found an item on the database,therefore, I tried with optional but when I test it I only get a null response besides an exception

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/compras", produces = "application/json")
public Optional<Compras> retrieveAllCompras(@RequestParam String id) {
    return Optional.of(compraRepository.findById(id)).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
```

I expect an exception when the item is not found in Database

Comment: try findById(id).get()

Answer (score 5):

`Optional.of` expects pure value. You can find the info in documentation as well,

```
/**
 * Constructs an instance with the described value.
 *
 * @param value the non-{@code null} value to describe
 * @throws NullPointerException if value is {@code null}
 */
private Optional(T value) {
    this.value = Objects.requireNonNull(value);
}
```

example,

```
jshell> Optional.of(100)
$2 ==> Optional[100]

jshell> Optional.of(null)
|  Exception java.lang.NullPointerException
|        at Objects.requireNonNull (Objects.java:221)
|        at Optional.<init> (Optional.java:107)
|        at Optional.of (Optional.java:120)
|        at (#1:1)
```

If your value could be `null` at runtime, you can use `.ofNullable`,

```
jshell> Optional.ofNullable(null)
$3 ==> Optional.empty
```

**ALSO**
The idea of functional programming is to return a value for all the inputs, instead of throwing `Exception` which breaks the function composition.

```
jshell> Function<Integer, Optional<Integer>> f = x -> Optional.of(x + 1)
f ==> $Lambda$23/0x0000000801171c40@6996db8

jshell> Function<Integer, Optional<Integer>> g = x -> Optional.of(x * 2)
g ==> $Lambda$24/0x0000000801172840@7fbe847c

jshell> f.apply(5).flatMap(x -> g.apply(x))
$13 ==> Optional[12]
```

**So in your example you can treat `Optional.empty()` as item not found, but Spring will consider that as `200` as well which is still better than throwing `500`.** You might want to send `404` to be accurate.

```
@GetMapping(
  value = "/compras", 
  produces = "application/json"
)
public Optional<Compras> retrieveAllCompras(@RequestParam String id) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(compraRepository.findById(id)); //will response as 200 even when no item found
}
```

You can use [`ResponseEntity<A>` to set specific http status](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26550981/432903)

**The traditional way of responding `404` is [defining specific exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54539641/432903).**

```
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

@GetMapping(
  value = "/compras", 
  produces = "application/json"
)
public Compras retrieveAllCompras(@RequestParam String id) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(compraRepository.findById(id))
                   .orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "item not found"))
}
```

Comment: pretty nice, i should add optional.empty and if so return the new response by telling item not found right?, thanks  a lot !

Comment: Yes, you can set http response code to be `404`. Spring by default either let you send back `200` if everything goes well or `500` if you throw generic Exception. But as you know `500` represents Server Error. In your example if item is not found its ideally `404`.

Comment: @Santiagomolanoperdomo I added an example that will send `404` when `Optional.empty`

Comment: Thanks a Lot!, I did not know about ResponeStatusException, I did it by creating a new Class, thank you so much!

Comment: this is indeed a definition of an excellent answer! plus one!

Answer (score 1):

Think about the types here, if you want to return Optional, and you will do an `.orElse`, you have to wrap it again. It wold be a way to do:

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/compras", produces = "application/json")
public Optional<Compras> retrieveAllCompras(@RequestParam String id) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(compraRepository.findById(id)).
                     map(Optional::of).
                     orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Not found"));
```

I'll explain:

1. `Optional.ofNullable()` will return an `Optional<Compras>`, with the value `Optional("some compras")` or the value `Optional.Empty`
2. `map(Optional::of)` will wrap the optional again, so you will have `Optional[Optional<Compras>]` or (here the trick) Optional.Empty, because map doesn't wrap the Optional.Empty (that's his reason of being among us)
3. Finally, `orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Not found"))` will unpack your optional, in this case from `Optional[Optional<Compras>]` to `Optional<Compras>` or, in case of being `Optional.Empty` it will throw the exception

Answer (score 0):

You controller returns `Optional<Compras>`. This means there will not be `#get` method called. Your controller will return null if `Optional` value.

Change to: `public Compras retrieveAllCompras...` and you'll get your exception

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the object name and invoked method (`compraRepository.findById(id)`), your service is actually a repository. If it's a Spring Data repository then you should leave creation of the `Optional` to Spring Data: [Null Handling of Repository Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.nullability). So you'll have

```
compraRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new)
```